# Weird angle results when drone is flying

Tags: c, accelerometer, sensor-fusion

We use the L3GD20 gyro sensor and the LSM303DLHC accelerometer sensor in combination with the complementary filter to measure the angles of the drone.

If we simulate the angles of the drone with our hands, for example, if we tilt the drone forward, our x angle is positive. And if we tilt it backwards, our x angle is negative.

But if we activate our motors, the drone will always go to a negative x-angle. On top of that, the x-angle that used to be positive is now negative. Because the drone tries to compensate this angle, but the angles are inverted, the drone will never go back to its original state.

```
#define RAD_TO_DEG 57.29578
#define G_GAIN 0.070
#define AA 0.98
#define LOOP_TIME 0.02

void calculate_complementaryfilter(float* complementary_angles)
{
    complementary_angles[X] = AA * (complementary_angles[X] + gyro_rates[X] * LOOP_TIME) + (1 - AA) * acc_angles[X];
    complementary_angles[Y] = AA * (complementary_angles[Y] + gyro_rates[Y] * LOOP_TIME) + (1 - AA) * acc_angles[Y];
}

void convert_accelerometer_data_to_deg()
{
    acc_angles[X] = (float) atan2(acc_raw[X], (sqrt(acc_raw[Y] * acc_raw[Y] + acc_raw[Z] * acc_raw[Z]))) * RAD_TO_DEG;
    acc_angles[Y] = (float) atan2(acc_raw[Y], (sqrt(acc_raw[X] * acc_raw[X] + acc_raw[Z] * acc_raw[Z]))) * RAD_TO_DEG;
}

void convert_gyro_data_to_dps()
{
    gyro_rates[X] = (float)gyr_raw[X] * G_GAIN;
    gyro_rates[Y] = (float)gyr_raw[Y] * G_GAIN;
    gyro_rates[Z] = (float)gyr_raw[Z] * G_GAIN;
}
```

The problem isn't the shaking of the drone. If we put the motors on max speed and simulate the angles by hand, we get the right angles. Thus also the right compensation by the motors.

If we need to add more code, just ask.

Thankyou in advance.

Comment: Implement some logging and debug it. No one here has anything better than you have.

Comment: We have printed all of the data, everything works perfectly untill we let go of the drone and put the motors on. It works when we put on the motors and hold it by hand. We get the right values and the right angles.

Comment: As I said. Find a way to have the data logged when failing.

Comment: Perhaps the torque of the motors turn or tilt the drone in unexpected ways?

Comment: The tilting of the drone is not the problem. The measured angles are just wrong from the complementary filter.

Comment: I have no clue how a drone works, but still: Is the Z dimension's calculation missing in those two functions by intention?

Comment: The Z dimension is not needed, it is used for the yaw. Right now we only use the pitch and the roll. Which is the tilt in x- and y-axis. The yaw is not important for stabilization.

Comment: Ah thanks!-} Do you just observe a wrong sign, but the absolute values themselves look good, when you let the thingy go, or are the values simply garbage?

Comment: The gyro values are always good, but the accelerometer values seem all over the place. But they can't be random, because that would mean the complementary would give random values. And the complementary always gives a negative x angles and inverts the x-axis. (btw inverting the x-axis back doesn't help, because the complementary filter stays around  -10 degrees. So if we invert it back to 10 degrees, the problem is the same.)

Comment: Just out of the blue: Assuming those `*_raw` arrays are updated asynchronously by the hardware, which is much faster then your steering code and the drone dangles around heavily if you let it go, then you might use different values (especially the Z-values most likely do not change the same way when you do the simulation by hand) for the related X and Y angles in the calculations shown, leading to "wrong" correction results. Also why not use `double` all over the place?

Comment: What makes you assume that the bug is in the code posted?

Comment: Perhaps the accelerometer is very responsive and is affected by imbalance from motor rotation.

Comment: I don't know where the bug is or what the problem is. I just posted some code that might help.

Comment: Also tested the accelerometer on different settings, 2g, 4g, 8g, 16g and high  and low resolution. Same results.

Comment: Ok, so the usual 1st debugging actions have been completed? 1.) Code compiles without warnings on highest warning level, with all casts removed! 2.) Memory checkers for stack and heap show now issues!

Comment: Completely different approach: You are sure the drone's *running*  engines do not 1.) let collapse the power supply 2.) emit disturbing stray radiation, are EMC-compatible?

Comment: _"... from the complementary filter."_ - Do you mean the input `acc_angles[X]` is wrong? Or that's correct but the output is still wrong? The output `complementary_angles[X]` is calculated iteratively - how does it evolve? Does it jump straight to - the correct value, or what?

Comment: acc_anglex gives very high values and has a big range. For example -200 and after that +80. gyro_rates seem accurate. Complementary filter accumulates over time. It doesn't jump right away. But it always goes to around -10 and the drone stays there. But the complementary filter result should be +10

Comment: emc are compatible, power supply is good.emit distrubing radiation? We have tested the drone on full speed by hand and that worked.

Comment: Memory stack and heap show now issues, but we do have warnings. I will resolve this now.

Comment: no issues on stack and heap*

Comment: Sounds like a hardware issue, if "presence of the hand (human body)" fixes the problem.

Comment: The random casts do not inspire confidence in the quality of the code.

Comment: It appears your [Body-frame RPY angles of airplanes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:RPY_angles_of_airplanes.png) are messed up. Aircraft attitude dynamics generally uses a reference frame where the Roll-Pitch-Yaw axis are as shown. (this is an inverted reference compared to satellites (or that used in spaceflight-dynamics). You should always experience a positive (or in your case negative) rotation about the pitch axis during flight -- that is the Angle-of-Attack (measured between the mean chord line of the wing and relative wind). It is needed to balance lift with gravity.

Answer (score 0):

## Standard exhaustive methodology for this kind of problems

You can go top-bottom or bottom-top. In this case, I'm more inclined to think in a hardware related problem, but it is up to you:

#### Power related problem

When you take the drone with your hand and run motors at full throttle, do they have propellers installed?
Motors at full speed without propellers drawn only a fraction of their full load. When lifting drone weight, a voltage drop can cause electronic malfunction.

Alternative cause: shortcircuits/derivations?

#### Mechanical problem (a.k.a vibrations spoil sensor readings)

In the past, I've seen MEMS sensors suffer a lot under heavy vibrations (amplitude +-4g). And with "suffer a lot" I mean accelerometer not even registering gravity and gyros returning meaningless data.
If vibrations are significative, you need either a better frame for the drone or a better vibration isolation for the sensors.

#### SW issues (data/algorithm/implementation)

If it is definitely unrelated with power and mechanical aspects, you can log raw sensor data and process it offline to see if it makes sense.
For this, you need an implementation of the same algorithm embedded in the drone.
Here you will be able to discern between:

- Buggy/wrong embedded implementation.
- Algorithm fails under working conditions.
- Other: data looks wrong (problem reading), SW not reaching time cycle constraints.